# Fingerprint Hardware ID GetHexString

Tags: vb.net

I found a fingerprint class in C# [here](http://sowkot.blogspot.com/2008/08/generating-unique-keyfinger-print-for.html)

I'm trying to convert the function below to VB .NET but I am having issues with the line that reads s+ = (char)....Any help would be appreciated.

```
private static string GetHexString(byte[] bt)
{
    string s = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < bt.Length; i++)
    {
        byte b = bt[i];
        int n, n1, n2;
        n = (int)b;
        n1 = n & 15;
        n2 = (n >> 4) & 15;
        if (n2 > 9)
            s += ((char)(n2 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
        else
            s += n2.ToString();
        if (n1 > 9)
            s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
        else
            s += n1.ToString();
        if ((i + 1) != bt.Length && (i + 1) % 2 == 0) s += "-";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Is there  a better way to write this function in VB.NET?

Comment: This all is `string.Concat(bt.Select((b, i) => b.ToString("X2") + (i>0 & (i+1)%2 ==0?"-":"")));`

Comment: Which translates to VB.Net as: `String.Concat(bt.Select(Function(b, i) b.ToString("X2") + If(i > 0 And (i + 1) Mod 2 = 0, "-", "")))`

Comment: That doesn't work. Gives me an error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error BC36641 Lambda parameter 'b' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

Comment: It also repeats same error for "i"

Comment: As I said, that code replaces **everything** in that method. You can test it with `Dim bt As Byte() = {124, 67, 45, 89, 104, 56, 88} Dim result = String.Concat(bt.Select(Function(b, i) b.ToString("X2") + If(i > 0 And (i + 1) Mod 2 = 0, "-", "")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
s += ((char)(n1 - 10 + (int)'A')).ToString();
```

is the same as

```
s &= Chr((n1 - 10 + Asc("A")))
```